# VsCode intellisense for dependencies in package.json

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

When i'm writing my dependencies in my package.json it should have intellisense for the package i'm trying to put inside dependencies

ex:

"bootstr" => should show a list of sugestion with "bootstrap" in it...

I get a list with one item => "bootstr"

[image]

so it doesn't make any sense...

I've tried in all my other project and i'm getting this problem.
What is broken ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question. You say intellisense should show you a list of dependencies from bootstrap ? Is bootstrap already installed? Do you expect that installed dependencies should appear in intellisense? Where is intellisense going to take the dependencies from if not installed previously?

Comment: i don't know what happenned but now they are back... when you type a dependency, it show you the packages that match the current string you entered.

Comment: @Vince I have the same issue. package.json intellisense works on my computer at work, but it does not seem to work on my personal computer. I have a fairly similar setup on both machines. Do you know what setting in vscode controls this?

Comment: I think if figured out what my issue was. I have "*.json" rule in "files.associations" in vscode's settings

Comment: @sazzy4o: if you found the answer, please post the solution not in the comments but as an answer. This will help to find the solution because the questions will appears as resolved

Comment: @SteveB I added my answer. There are a lot of things that can cause this. I included a couple. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of potential causes of this problem. Here are a couple of issues that I have run into before:

## 1. VS Code Settings

### What to check:

Go to `settings.json` (there will be at least two of these for you, one for your workspace and one for your user)

1. Open settings:

`Ctrl+,` (or File->Preferences->Settings)

2. Open `settings.json`:
   [image: Settings navigate]
3. Make sure to check all versions of the settings:

[image: User and workspace]

I think there are a few settings that can cause this, so you might want to search for settings with `json`, but the `files.associations` is one that can break intellisense for `package.json`:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.json": "javascript"
},
```

### Fix:

Delete the `*.json` (or other json) entry

## 2. Malformed package.json

### What to check:

Make sure npm can parse your `package.json`

### Fix:

Make sure your package.json is properly formed (No missing comma, no extra brackets, no comments)